# Parsing HTML in PHP: get table onclick attribute value

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to parse HTML page to get data from table (basically I want to loop through all `tr` tags).

I have next questions:

1. How to skip `tr` in table head?
2. How to get `onclick` attribute value of `td` tag?
3. How to count `td` in each `tr`

HTML structure:

```
<tr>
  <td onclick="window.location='home.php?navi=148';">kkkk</td>
  <td>demo</td>
  <td>kkkk</td>
</tr>
```

i want to get **window.location='home.php?navi=148';**
Code that I am using:

```
$url = $html;
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

# Iterate over all the <a> tags
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $link) {
    # Show the <a href>
    print_r($link);
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using the DOM extension, but you missed DOMXPath. It allows you to use XPath expression to fetch part of the document. It can return node lists, or scalars.

### Basic Syntax

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xpath->evaluate($expression, $optionalContext);
```

### How to skip tr in table head?

This is possible but most of the time it is easier to do positive matches (all tr inside the tbody). Think about the tr inside a tfoot.

All tr inside tbody: `//table/tbody/tr`
All tr directly in table: `//table/tr`
All tr where the parent is not a thead `//table//tr[name(parent::*) != 'thead']`

### How to get onclick attribute value of td tag?

This is a scalar value - so you need to cast it to a string:

`string(//table/tbody/tr/td/@onclick)`

### How to count td in each tr

This will require a combination, first fetching the tr, then the count with the tr as context:

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//table/tbody/tr') as $tr) {
  var_dump($xpath->evaluate('count(td)', $tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get node Value?

```
   foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $link) {
    # Show the <a href>

    echo $link->nodeValue; //td value inside
    echo "<br />";
```

}

Comment: i want to get onlclick value ??

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using php why don't you use javascript to achieve what you want..

The code for doing this is as follows:

```
$('#tableId tr').each(function(){
    defaultData[i] = new Array();
    j = 0;
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        defaultData[i][j] = $(this).html();
        if (defaultData[i][j].length > 150)
        {                
            defaultData[i][j] = $(this).find('select').val();
        }
        j++;
    });
    i++;
});
```

Comment: need to save values in db and some other stuff 
my code works just need value of onclick inside td

Comment: I m not getting what are you trying to say.. please explain so that I can understand and give a appropriate solution to your issue..